# Ember-cli & fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, ember-cli

Senario is:
mcalendar: `model`,
mevent: `model`,
relationship: mcalendar `has_many` mevents,
in the `mcalendar.show` `route` I have:

```
model: function(params) {
return this.store.find('mcalendar', params.mcalendar_id);
},
```

what I want to do is:
to have a function in the `mcalendar.show` `route` to return all `mevents` of `mcalendar` in the form of an array. Something like this:

```
A HOOK(maybe afterModel): function(){
 //return all mevents like:
    return {
      events: Ember.A([
      {
       title: mevent.get('title'),
       start: mevent.get('start')
 }])
```

the purpose is to use this array for feeding `fullCalendar`. I have tried some ways but none of them was successful.
`Ember cli`: 0.2.7
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
afterModel: function () {

var _this = this;
var model = this.modelFor(this.routeName);

  return model.get('mevents').then(function(mevents) {
    var allMevents = mevents.map(function(mevent){
      return {
                title: mevent.get('title'),
                start: mevent.get('start')
              };
    });

    _this.controllerFor('mcalendars.show').set('events', allMevents);
  });
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

are your mevents returned in the payload when requesting mcalendar? if so, you could do this in the setupController hook instead like...

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('events', model.get('mevents').toArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer though it did not work, but I combined you answer with some other options and works very well now. I post my answer, maybe it will be useful.